# Firefox/jQuery bug using Twitter Bootstrap popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, twitter-bootstrap, getcomputedstyle

I'm getting this error using Firefox but not webkit browser when I invoke a [Twitter Bootstrap popover](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers).

```
NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS: Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMWindow.getComputedStyle] @ http://localhost/assets/thirdParty/jquery/jquery-1.8.3.js:6825
```

The error is on line 6825 of jquery.js:

```
var computed = window.getComputedStyle( elem, null );
```

[This post seems to address this question](http://siderite.blogspot.com/2009/07/jquery-firexof-error-could-not-convert.html) but when I tried implement their solution (shown below) that had no effect. The post is 4 years old so the version of jQuery is different and I'd think can explain why this solution no longer works.

```
if (elem == document) elem = document.body; 
var computed = window.getComputedStyle( elem, null );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered my own question. The problem is that my popover content ended with a comment. So this didn't work:

```
<div class="popover">
    some content
</div><!--popover-->
```

whereas this did:

```
<div class="popover">
    some content
</div>
```